# Saving a very simple MusicSequence into MIDI doesn't reproduce sound

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, midi, musicsequence

I'm trying to save a very basic one note MusicSequence ([MusicSequence Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/MusicSequence_Reference/Reference/reference.html)) into a MIDI file. The file is being written right now and the duration of the note also (if I put duration 4 then the MIDI file lasts 2 secs, if I change it to 2 then it lasts 1 sec as it should) but there's no sound being reproduced and if I look at the MIDI file in Logic there's no information neither. Seems like the note duration gets written but the note's note isn't.

What could be happening?

```
+ (MusicSequence)getSequence
{
    MusicSequence mySequence;
    MusicTrack myTrack;
    NewMusicSequence(&mySequence);
    MusicSequenceNewTrack(mySequence, &myTrack);

    MIDINoteMessage noteMessage;
    MusicTimeStamp timestamp = 0;
    noteMessage.channel = 0;
    noteMessage.note = 4;
    noteMessage.velocity = 90;
    noteMessage.releaseVelocity = 0;
    noteMessage.duration = 4;

    if (MusicTrackNewMIDINoteEvent(myTrack, timestamp, &noteMessage) != noErr) NSLog(@"ERROR creating the note");
    else NSLog(@"Note added");

    return mySequence;
}
```

Comment: Uhm, what library is `MusicSequence` from? Without further information, we cannot help you. -1 for unanswerable question (for now).

Comment: MusicSequence is from the framework AudioToolbox/MusicPlayer.h http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/MusicSequence_Reference/Reference/reference.html sorry about not clarifying that. Edited the original post to incude it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try writing a note that is > 20 and < 109 ([midi note range](http://www.phys.unsw.edu.au/jw/notes.html)). While 4 may be technically valid, it is outside the range of normal midi notes.

Also, a useful function working with Core Audio/MusicPlayer etc. is CAShow() - so try `CAShow(sequence)` to view the sequence data.

Comment: Does `CAShow` print info to the console? Nothing shows up for me.